# How to start a pbap session with CreateSession

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I'm developping a smartphone bluetooth simulator for my company, in python 2.7 with bluez 5.48 on Ubuntu 18.04, and 5.37 on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything is up-to-date, and I already corvered all the `adapter/device/agent-api` from the `bluez` doc, through `dbus`. It works well without any problem (settings, pairing, connection...).

Now I'm trying to add a `PBAP` service (`PBAP PSE`) to share the phonebook, that sync with a car system (`PBAP PCE`), with the `obex-api`.
As far as I understand, I first call:

```
CreateSession()
```

with `Target = pbap`, but it returns:

```
"Unable to find service record"
```

And that's the blocking point, I have no idea why, nor what a service record means.
I tried to start profile with `sdptool`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.
The tests in `bluez` repo give me the same error.
I tried a lot of different config, profile, bluetooth adapters etc... no success.

Thanks for your help!

bluez doc : https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Comment: Thanks for your edit CKE !

Comment: Did you check whether obexd is running? Also try to check the dbus service "org.bluez.obex" using dbus-send/gdbus-send, whether service exists or not. If exists, try explore the API presence using "dbus introspection".

Comment: Yes, the service obexd is running (checked with ps), and accessible with d-feet (dbus explorer). And I can instanciate org.bluez.obex.Client1 object.